# How to use a string variable into re.findall?

Tags: python, regex

I used Python to find a word started and ended with specified letters through a text file. But, I have some problem with using a string variable inside `re.findall` command. Could you please give me any suggestion?

```
import re
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1]+'.txt', "r")
data = f.read()
re.findall(r'\b'+str(sys.argv[2])'\w+', data)
```

Could you please expanding this code to find a word started and ended with defined letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `re.compile` function, not sure what your code does but with your given example:

```py
import re
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1]+'.txt',"r")
data = f.read()
regex = re.compile(r"\b" + str(sys.argv[2]) + r"\w+")
re.findall(regex, data)
```

If you want to get words starting and ending with specified letters you could use something like:

```py
import re
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1]+'.txt',"r")
data = f.read()
                   # starting with 'a' and ending with 'w'
regex = re.compile("^a" + str(sys.argv[2]) + "w$")
re.findall(regex, data)
```

Comment: Isn't it w$ to check if the last letter is a w?

Comment: I just used the op's example.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. However, isn't it w$ to check if the last letter is a w?

Comment: Yes it's `w$` instead of `\w+`.

Comment: Ok, I already upvoted but maybe edit it in as a suggestion :)

Comment: @GuvenDegirmenci thanks, but I get nothing when I run first section of your modified command!

Comment: Are you sure you need to use the regex `\bsometext\w+` to match? Can we see an example of your input?

Comment: Sure. my text file contains "I was searching my books yesterday". An strange thing is to say that when I use re.findall(r'\bs\w+', data), the output result is ['searching']

Comment: My bad, when you write `\b` as a string, the python itself escapes `b`, in order to tell the compile function that this is `\b` indeed, you either escape the backslash `\\b` or write as regex `r"\b"` instead of string. I edited the answer and it should work now.

Comment: @GuvenDegirmenci Thank you very much for your contribution. I will be deeply grateful, if you modify the following to work for inputs.

 regex = re.compile(r"\b" + str(sys.argv[2]) + r"\S"+str(sys.argv[3])+r"\b")

Comment: What do you want to match with this expression? And also what are you planning to give input as argument 2 and 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207850/discussion-between-guven-degirmenci-and-martin).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import sys

thefile = open(sys.argv[1]+".txt", "r")

for line in thefile:
    if re.match(sys.argv[2]+"(.*)"+sys.argv[3]+"(.*)(.*)", line):
        print line
```

argv[1]  is a file name

argv[2] is a starting letter of word,

argv[3] is a ending letter of word,

you can search a word using starting and ending letter of words